# Error: can't determine file type of stat error: No such file or directory Error: Can't determine file type of Practice_populations.snps.vcf

Tags: command-line, error-handling

I am pretty new to ubuntu and I am trying to learn how to use vcftools to filter SNP data.  I keep getting the same error after trying to run my code: Stat error: no such file or directory, Error: can't determine file type of Practice.populations.snps.vcf

I have tried renaming my working directory and trying again, I have double checked that my file is actually a vcf and nothing seems to work.

[This is a picture of what my code looked like the last time I tried to run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxKr7.jpg)

(base) sample@sample-VirtualBox:~/Practice.Oct.20$ vcftools --vcf Practice.populations.snps.vcf --max-missing 0.05 --recode --recode-INFO-all --out prac.mm

VCFtools - 0.1.16
(C) Adam Auton and Anthony Marcketta 2009

Parameters as interpreted:
--vcf Practice.populations.snps.vcf
--recode-INFO-all
--max-missing 0.05
--out prac.mm
--recode

stat error: No such file or directory
Error: Can't determine file type of Practice.populations.snps.vcf
(base) sample@sample-VirtualBox:~/Practice.Oct.20$

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using version 20.04.2

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Pictures can not be searched, often have bits cut off and require anyone trying to help to leave the question to see the picture.

Comment: sorry, I just added the code as text that I have been working with today